# Does reminder app need database to work? -flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart

I want to make reminders app, and for that I will use **FlutterLocalNotification** because when I searched I saw that it is working in the background.
My question  is should I use database for the reminders or not?
and can I use **FlutterLocalNotification** with a specific time? I mean let the user to pick the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried [flutter_local_notificaitons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) using it you can send the user local notifications in a specific time even when the app is closed. So I think it's the way to go. There are even some fancy ways to specify time patterns.

If you want try out this [project](https://github.com/moneer-muntazah/local_notifications) I created it a while back to test the package. You will need to change line **80** in **main.dart** to use your own time zone.

You will need some local storage otherwise the user data will just not persist when she closes the app. There are many packages for this. Some are lighter then others. It depends on how big your app is so check them out and see what works.

Comment: Thank you so much!
well my app is small and simple, what would you recommend local storage type for me to use?

Comment: You are very welcome  Try [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) but I'm not sure if it is the best option if you have a multi user app where people can log in and out if not it should work out just fine :)